# URL Rewrite a Query String

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have Google'ed long for this but can't find an answer.

I have this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?tip=1
```

(respectively `www.mysite.com/?tip=1`)

And want it to rewrite to:

```
www.mysite.com/tip/1
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the inverse: www.mysite.com/tip/1 to www.mysite.com/index.php?tip=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable rewrite module in your apache config and put the following settings on the .htaccess file your base folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule   ^tip/(.*)  /index.php?tip=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```